# filtrar y extraer archivos de una carpeta de nombres específicos

Tags: .bat

Como puedo hacer para que un archivo .bat u otro método, me filtre por nombre, seleccione y copie en otra carpeta. Por ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la imagen e muestra, solo quiero extraer todos los archivos que lleven en su nombre "palaciodehierro", y los copie y me los mueva a otra carpeta.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una solución sencilla es utilizar el buscador y escribir PALACIODEHIERRO, te filtrará sólo esos y de ahí puedes copiarlos manualmente.

Comment: Buen día Rodrigo, si, como dices eso sería lo más sencillo, pero necesito hacerlo de manera automática y por eso me quería apoyar en archivos .bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he creado esta sencilla script para solucionar tu problema, introduce la unidad en donde quieres buscar los archivos y el nombre para filtrar. Este proceso puede tardar unos cuantos segundos dependiendo del rendimiento de tu pc. Después te enseñara todos los que ha encontrado y posteriormente te preguntara donde quieres pegarlos. Un saludo!

```
@echo off
title=Buscador de archivos
color 30
echo.
echo.
echo= BUSCADOR DE ARCHIVOS =
echo.
echo.

:retorno
echo.
set ruta=0
set cadena=exit
set /p ruta= Unidad de disco (C, D, etc.):
if %ruta%==0 goto retorno
echo.

:error
set /p cadena= Archivo (nombre o parte del mismo):
if %cadena%==exit goto error
echo.
echo.
where /t /r %ruta%:\ *%cadena%* > resultados.txt
more resultados.txt
echo.
echo.
set /p copiar= ¿Desea copiar el archivo? (s/n)
echo.
if %copiar%==s (goto next1) else (goto next2)
:next1
set /p destino= Indicar la ruta completa de destino:
set copiar=<resultados.txt
xcopy %copiar% %destino%
del resultados.txt
echo archivo copiado en %destino%
:next2
echo.
set /p seguir= ¿Volver a buscar? (s/n):
```

Se que no me he currado mucho la interfaz pero bueno es funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Solo utiliza este código y te copiará todo lo que contenga el nombre entre asteriscos.
Elimina los espacios que están después y antes de los asteriscos.

```
xcopy "C:\Carpeta_de_origen\ejemplo\* PALACIODEHIERRO *" "E:\Carpeta_de_destino\ejemplo\" /y
```